# how to fix TypeError: called match pattern must be a type in Python 3.10

Tags: pattern-matching, python-3.10

Trying to learn Python 3.10 pattern matching.  Tried this example after reading [8.6.4.9. Mapping Patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#mapping-patterns)

```
>>> match 0.0:
...  case int(0|1):
...   print(1)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: called match pattern must be a type
>>>
```

Especially the note on built-in types, including int.  How should I code to test for an integer value of 0 or 1 (the example in the doc) and not get this error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Executing your exact lines on a Python 3.10 console does not print anything. Then, changing 0.0 to 0 or 1 prints 1. I'm unsure how you got that error, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 7):

I fell into a gotcha:

```py
match 0.0
  case int:
    print(1)
```

effectively redefines int, so the next time I tried the match I posted, it failed since *my* int was shadowing the built in

Comment: Ughh that makes it  seem like it's just waiting to introduce hard-to-debug problems.

Answer (score 5):

For structural pattern matching, the class pattern requires parentheses around the class name.

For example:

```py
x = 0.0
match x:
    case int():
        print('I')
    case float():
        print('F')
    case _:
        print('Other')
```

Answer (score 0):

> How should I code to test for an integer value of 0 or 1

The right answer is to use **OR-Patterns**, described in [PEP 622](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#combining-multiple-patterns-or-patterns):

> Multiple alternative patterns can be combined into one using |. This
> means the whole pattern matches if at least one alternative matches.
> **Alternatives are tried from left to right and have a short-circuit
> property, subsequent patterns are not tried if one matched**.

```py
x = 1
match x:
    case int(0 | 1):
        print('case of x = int(0) or x = int(1)')
    case _:
        print('x != 1 or 0')
```

> Output: 'case of x = int(0) or x = int(1)'

**Type insensitive** would be like this:

```py
x = 1.0
match x:
    case 0 | 1:
        print('case of x = 0 or x = 1')
    case _:
        print('x != 1 or 0')
```

> Output: 'case of x = 0 or x = 1'

---

In case you want to check for **each case separately**, you would do:

```py
x = 1.0
match x:
    case int(0):
        print('x = 0')
    case int(1):
        print('x = 1')
    case _:
        print('x != 1 or 0')
```

> Output: `x != 1 or 0`

```py
x = 1.0
match x:
    case 0:
        print('x = 0')
    case 1:
        print('x = 1')
    case _:
        print('x != 1 or 0')
```

> Output: `x = 1`