# Python match/case by dictionary key/values

Tags: python, dictionary, types, switch-statement, python-3.10

I would like to clean my code from excessive if/else and translate to match/case. However, I am unable to access the value by key. I get the error `called match pattern must be a type`.

My code:

```
match message.channel.id: #int type 123123
    case channels.get("EventID") | channels.get("AnnouncmentsID"): #list of values int types {"EventID" : 123213} | {"PetsID : 234234}
        #some code

    case channels.get("DeathID"): #value int type {"DeathID" :123123}
        if message.attachments:
           #some code
    ###Same cases
    case _:
        pass
```

I tried explicitly changing int/string types, use the dict[key] and dict.get('key') keys directly. Nothing comes out.

Comment: on what line the error occurs ?

Comment: 2 line and 4 line on 'case' `called match pattern must be a type `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix TypeError: called match pattern must be a type in Python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918623/how-to-fix-typeerror-called-match-pattern-must-be-a-type-in-python-3-10)

Comment: I saw this thread, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem (
For some reason case + dict doesn't work in conjunction

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `int` to `list`. Use `|` for matching multiple literals in match statement:

```
case channels.get("EventID") | channels.get("AnnouncmentsID") | channels.get("PetsID") | channels.get("Guild MomentsID"):
```

Described in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching)

Comment: Btw the problem remains. I get the error `called match pattern must be a type`.